# JOIN two tables with different granularity

Tags: sql, postgresql, clickhouse

I have
Table A:

| id | country | platform | retargeting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Italy | iOS | true |
| 1 | France | iOS | NULL |
| 2 | Italy | Android | false |
| 2 | Italy | NULL | NULL |

And table B:

| id | country | platform | retargeting | installs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Italy | iOS | true | 99 |
| 1 | France | iOS | false | 100 |
| 2 | Italy | Android | false | 500 |
| 2 | Italy | Android | NULL | 400 |
| 2 | France | iOS | false | 200 |
| 2 | Italy | iOS | false | 300 |

Different tables (only 1 column) because A comes from our web as `source` and B comes from API as `result`, so I need to get installs, but from API I can get it by different granularity, so I need to `SUM` and `GROUP` data in table B by granularity from table A.

I expect this result:

| id | country | platform | retargeting | installs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Italy | iOS | true | 99 |
| 1 | France | iOS | NULL | 100 |
| 2 | Italy | Android | false | 900 |
| 2 | Italy | NULL | NULL | 1200 |

So, as you can see for last row I had to `SUM` these rows because source table has granularity at `country` level and result table with installs has different granularity:

| id | country | platform | retargeting | installs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Italy | Android | false | 500 |
| 2 | Italy | Android | NULL | 400 |
| 2 | Italy | iOS | false | 300 |

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
with tot_installs as (
select id, country, sum(installs) total
from B
group by id, country),

country_platform_installs as (
select id, country, platform, sum(installs) cp_total
from B
group by id, country, platform
)

select A.id, A.country, A.platform, A.retargeting,
 case 
 when cp_total is null then total
 else cp_total
 end as installs

from A
    inner join tot_installs
        on (tot_installs.id=A.id and tot_installs.country=A.country)
    left join country_platform_installs cpi
        on (cpi.id=A.id and cpi.country=A.country and cpi.platform=A.platform)
```